# Can we Only work with one broadcast receiver?

Tags: android

Can We only work with one broadcast receiver ?

I have some broadcast receiver and they works well , :

[Note: Only one BroadcastReceiver class can be specified per application. Should you need to incorporate two or more BroadcastReceivers from different SDKs, you will need to create your own BroadcastReceiver class that will receive all broadcasts and call the appropriate BroadcastReceivers for each type of Broadcast.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#google-play-tracking)

Comment: it's one receiver for each filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<application>` can contain multiple `<receiver>` and each `<receiver>` can contain multiple `<intent-filter>`. E.g.:

```
<application>

    <receiver android:name="ReceiverA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION1"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="ReceiverB">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION2" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION3" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

But you can only have one `"com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"` - that is IMO what the documentation means.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may use a single **BroadcastReceiver** to catch all action strings. Make sure you do add all the action string in your **IntentFilter** used by that receiver to make it work.

Comment: what do you mean? elaborate more